# AngularJS $scope related to 'as myController'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a MainController and a PageController. The MainController manages data and gets a $scope,$http as a parameter. I use it like ng-controller="MainController"
I use PageController to manage the tabs on the website, so it has like **this.setTab** and **this.isTabSelected** and I use it like *ng-controller="PageController as pager".*

if I use the alias 'as XXY' I can't seem to access $scope, can I only use $scope WHILE using as and referring to as pager.setTab?

My Goal is to $emit a notification when the page changes, but I can not use $scope and not refer pager, because pager is the global controller (root scope basically) so it is like this:

... ng-controller="PageController as pager" ...

.......ng-controller="MainController" .........

Any clearance on $scope in combination with 'as XXY' and this. Thanks

Comment: add some code that demonstrates how you are using the name od the controller, please.

Answer (score 0):

The controllerAs syntax is the preferred syntax for AngularJS. When you use this syntax you do not bind controllers to templates using the $scope directly. Instead use instance methods and properties of the controller.

The $scope is still used within the controller to bind and emit events, watchers, and call $apply().

Comment: nevermind, I just got it to work with $broadcast instead of $emit